# NET clr.dll описание

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день, где можно узнать какие классы, методы находятся в clr.dll для .net

Comment: А зачем это вам, если не секрет?

Comment: для оптимизации приложения, хочу определить где больше всего происходит загрузка ПК в каком классе => методе(есть не только приложение но и набор библиотек )

Comment: Мне кажется, для такого лучше не это, а обыкновенный профайлер. Он покажет реально узкие места.

Comment: попробую спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clr.dll - это не библиотека классов. Это, практически, сама среда .NET - код, который отвечает за выполнение .NET приложения, а не просто стандартный набор классов и методов.

Стандартные классы разбросаны по другим dll. Базовые и совсем встроенные классы в основном находятся в mscorlib.dll и в system.dll.

Вот полный список того, что можно считать стандартным: [Библиотека классов платформы .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx). В описании каждого типа указана сборка, в которой этот тип объявлен.

Comment: это понятно... спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Reflector поможет показать реализацию классов и методов почти у любой сборки.

Правда, он стал платным, но можно подобрать бесплатный аналог:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector